# What causes dev mode to perform so incredibly slow?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-dev-mode

At the moment gwt development mode is extremely slow when preparing the page and while actually using my application. If i compile and run using runjettyrun everything works at a satisfactory speed but with gwt everything is very slow. I have tried forcing gwt to compile only for gecko1_8 but it's not much help. What else can i try?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2897601/116472, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4069437/116472 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/9047686/116472 ?

Comment: This comes in a little late but i think it might have something to do with the inherits tag in my gwt.xml that points smartgwt packages

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I'm experiencing the same issue with smartgwt.

Answer (score 1):

The dev mode is slow because your code is compiled on the fly by the code server.

Did you try to use super-dev-mode instead? With super-dev-mode, the code is compiled before you access it with only the permutation corresponding to the browser and locale you are using.

Comment: isn't that in the experimental phase?

Comment: Yes, it is :  `Super Dev Mode is an experimental replacement for GWT's Development Mode`. But I use it everyday and it works perfectly : you won't want to use dev mode anymore :) The only drawback is that in case of error, you don't have a clear stacktrace. In this case, just fallback to dev mode to fix the bug.

Comment: I use it with chrome every day. I just tried with FF and it works like a charm.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle True, I also had to fallback to dev mode to fix a bug. So I just stick with Dev mode, but it is so slow...

Answer (score 0):

Using the G1GC garbage collector made a big difference for me on OSX.